# dlply function not being applied to subset

Tags: r, plyr

**Data:**

```
test_dat<-data.frame("ID"=c(rep("a",times=19),rep("b",times=20)),
                      "time"=seq(1,39,1),
                      "AMT"=c(0.5,  0.5,    0.5,    0.5,    0.5,    0.5,    0.5,    0.5,    0.5,    0.005,  
                              0.005,    0.005,  0.003,  0.0088, 0.0074, 0.006,  0.0023, 0.0028, 
                              0.0034,0.5,   0.5,    0.5,    0.5,    0.5,    0.5,    0.5,    0.5,    
                              0.5,  0.005,  0.005,  0.005,  0.0037, 0.0088, 0.0079, 0.005,  
                              0.006,    0.0034, 0.0042, 0.0029),
                      "ND_format"=c(TRUE,   TRUE,   TRUE,   TRUE,   TRUE,   TRUE,   TRUE,   TRUE,   TRUE,   
                                    TRUE,   TRUE,   TRUE,   FALSE,  FALSE,  FALSE,  FALSE,  FALSE,  
                                    FALSE,  FALSE,  TRUE,   TRUE,   TRUE,   TRUE,   TRUE,   TRUE,   TRUE,   
                                    TRUE,   TRUE,   TRUE,   TRUE,   TRUE,   FALSE,  FALSE,  FALSE,  TRUE,   
                                    FALSE,  FALSE,  FALSE,  FALSE))
```

Problem: 
I am trying to use the `NADA` package to compute maximum likelihood regression on a censored data object. I have a larger data set where I would like to apply a function across subsets of one dataframe. See below:

```
library(NADA)
library(plyr)
cen_objects<-dlply(test_dat, .(ID), function(x,y,z) cenreg(Cen(test_dat$AMT,test_dat$ND_format)~as.numeric(test_dat$time)))
summary(cen_objects)
str(cen_objects[[1]])
cen_objects[[1]]@survreg$coefficients

interceptz<-ldply(names(cen_objects),function(x) cen_objects[[x]]@survreg$coefficients)
interceptz$ID<-names(cen_objects)
interceptz
```

The problem is that this currently does not apply the function to each unique "ID" (i.e. the intercepts should be different for "a" and "b"). And when I try this:

```
cen_objects<-dlply(test_dat, .(ID), function(x,y,z) cenreg(Cen(AMT,ND_format)~as.numeric(time)))
```

I get an

> "Error in Cen(AMT, ND_format) : object 'AMT' not found"

Thanks for the help, I am new to split-apply-combine and I am afraid I do not pass functions correctly. Detailed answers will help me write these functions better in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're having is in the function you're supplying to `dlply`.  You're writing it as being passed 3 variables `x`, `y` and `z` and it is being passed only a single value, which is the data frame split chunk by `ID`. This is why it can't find any of the variables and throws an error.

If you use:

```
cen_objects <- dlply(test_dat, .(ID), function(x) cenreg(Cen(x$AMT,x$ND_format)~as.numeric(x$time)))
```

It should work just fine.